# Smart Folders stopped working after upgrade to High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, finder-tag, smart-folders

I have several Smart Folders that find items by tag, e.g., tag = red. After upgrading to High Sierra, these Smart Folders stopped working, i.e., they show no files. (The files are still tagged.)

I tried creating new Smart Folders that find items by tag and those don't work either.

Any ideas on what's wrong or how to fix it?